# How to write css for fit a website for IPHONE and IPAD?

Tags: iphone, html, css, ipad

I searched several times to make css for fit my website for IPHONE and IPAD.but got few methods to solve this with using meta tags and css styles for these devices.but I have few questions about this.

1.need to add individual meta tag for landscape and portrait in both iphone and ipad?

2.how to add css for for landscape and portrait?

3.will this work without adding meta tags(with css)?

4.I'm tring to add a world map for fit screen for both iphone and ipad,then will I need to re size the map image?

5.what is the theory for change the meta tag value with each devices and each positions?

Comment: you don't change a meta tag, blocks of CSS are separated with conditions like this `@media screen and (min-width: 400px) and (orientation: portrait)`

Comment: @popnoodles- thanks for the reply.but what is the meta tag have to use?

Comment: there is no meta tag. It's all in the CSS. Look at the 1 answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh653584.aspx

This is about responsive webdesign